# How to update a page fragment dynamically as the user switches between the tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity with three tabs, and the three tabs are being populated with a recycler view while fetch data using a JSONHttp Request with Volley. However, the problem is that the first time the data is fetched, it get's populated. However, I am unable to find a way to fetch data again (like refresh it) when I switch from one tab to another.

A snippet of what I am doing is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Class name TAG to be used for logging
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Variables
    private User user;
    private static ArrayList<> items;
    private Fragment Fragment1, Fragment2;

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("USER");
        fetchItems();
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.d("Main", "Switching tab");

                // Update the view
                super.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        });

    }

 public void fetchJobs(){
        items = new ArrayList<>();

JsonArrayRequest getItems = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + "items.json?", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray o) {
// Get JSon from Http request, this code works fine..
// items array is populated with the desired response
                    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
....

}
```

If I call fetchItems() when I switch to a tab to refresh the list it does not get repopulated with the new entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
       //Do what you want to do here
    }
}
```

in each child fragment of viewPager,so each time the fragment is shown in viewpager it will get called. and can make the necessary changes.  thanks if it doesn't wokr please note down.